# 404 after site restoration with Akeeba Kickstart

Tags: installation, akeebabackup, localhost, backups, troubleshooting

I have received a backup of a client's website as a `.jpa` file and I'm trying to install it locally into **MAMP**. The site is using **Joomla! 3.6.5 Stable** and **Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ]**

All seemed to go pretty smoothly right up until I went to view my website in the browser and I received a 404 error.

I have tried deleting `.htaccess.bak` and `.htaccess.admintools` from my local installation but I am still getting the same error.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read through the Akeeba documentation? It's extremely detailed, so I'm sure you'll find your answer there

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the site URL being set as the live site rather than the local installation in MAMP, I set it to the local URL and now the site works

Comment: Note that in most cases you don't need to set the live url configuration variable.